# Input tipo Data está retornando a data invertida

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho este site http://tamandareplaza.com.br/ e estou tentando fazer o formulário dele se comunicar com o sistema de reservas.
Como se pode ver na área de "FAÇA AQUI A SUA RESERVA", a data que o cliente informa é no formato dd/mm/aaaa . Porém quando é enviada, na url ela aparece como yyyy/mm/dd e acaba dando um bug no sistema! Porque ao ser enviada o retorno dela é invertido? Como resolver?

Comment: Coloque o código para podermos averiguar. **Obs:** Geralmente, no banco de dados, o campo da data, do tipo 'date' ou 'datetime' é invertido (formato americano)...

Comment: Conforme verifiquei no código da página ela utiliza Angular.JS para tratamento dos campos de data, utilizando o model "date", que por padrão utiliza o formato americano para datas, ainda que a visualização apresentada seja DD/MM/YYYY (Dia/Mês/Ano), esta conversão é feita pelo próprio angular. Vamos ver se alguém que entende consegue te ajudar... Para isto edita a tua questão por favor e coloca o código referente ao formulário pelo menos e também a parte do envio, feita em javascript.

Comment: No caso, do Angular JS, você pode incluir o locate `angular-locale_pt-br.js` para que ele utilize a biblioteca em português.

Comment: Podes explicar onde vais consumir essa data? estás a mandar para o servidor e vai ser usada numa base de dados por exemplo?